# ScrollViewer CanContentScroll Property not Found (Windows 8.1 Universal App)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to get a ScrollView to logical scroll instead of physically. After reading up online on how to do this, most sources say to set the CanContentScroll property to False. However, when attempting to do this, it seems that ScrollViewer doesn't have this property.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="TestScroll" CanContentScroll="True"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" Margin="66,215,1020,10" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="TestPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

And the error(s) thrown:

```
Error   1   The member "CanContentScroll" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

`Error  2   The property 'CanContentScroll' was not found in type 'ScrollViewer'`

I am developing for Windows 8.1, creating a universal app. I feel like I'm missing something like a reference or something incredibly simple because everywhere else that I have looked, it just works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, Windows 8.1 Universal Apps do not use WPF. They use WinRT. That's why you can't find the `CanContentScroll` property, it simply doesn't exist in WinRT's `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Thank you @almulo, this helps clarify some other things for me as well. I was able to figure it out by using a WinRT ScrollViewer property (VerticalSnapPoints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, using the VerticalSnapPointsType="Mandatory" property for ScrollViewer instead.

Comment: Glad you found it! I was looking at the Snap Points thing, but haven't really developed any Win8 so wasn't sure :) Does it work out of the box? It snaps to your items boundaries?

Comment: Yup, straight out of the box. There are several different options (5 actually): None, Optional, OptionalSingle, Mandatory, MandatorySingle. I found these on Page 112 of Windows 8.1 Apps with XAML and C# Unleashed, found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dd9PAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA112).